# Find out common value from two different Type Array

Tags: ios, swift, higher-order-functions, swift5

I have two **Array** with different **Data Types**

Assume Array1 is an [**String**] array of **String**

Assume Array 2 is an [Custom Objects] array of **Struct**

Pls find a code

```
struct ScanData{
    var serialNo : String!
    var intNo : String!
    init(serialNo : String, intNo : String) {
        self.serialNo = serialNo
        self.intNo = intNo
    }
}
var validScannedData : [String] = []
var inValidScannedData : [String] = []
var arrayObj = [ScanData(serialNo: "12220116033", intNo: "SN6AT4.270"),ScanData(serialNo: "12198144025", intNo: "SN6AT4.280"),ScanData(serialNo: "12222383027", intNo: "SN6AT4.130"),ScanData(serialNo: "12198213032", intNo: "SN6AT5.260"),ScanData(serialNo: "", intNo: "")]
//print(arrayObj)
//ScanData(serialNo: "12199690049", intNo: "SN6AT6U100")
var localArray = ["12220116033","12198144025","12222383027","12198213032","12199690049"]
let tempArray = arrayObj.filter { data in
    return data.serialNo != "" || data.intNo != ""
}
print(tempArray.count)
```

Now we want to get common values from **localArray** and **tempArray** by matching **serialNo** key

Finally i want to have **Array of String** Format in **validScannedData** object

Expected Output :

Valid data : **["12220116033","12198144025","12222383027","12198213032"]**

Invalid data : **["12199690049"]**

I tried this but its prints custom object array

```
let a = tempArray.filter () { localArray.contains($0.serialNo) }
print(a)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Apply a `map(/.serialNo)` before the `filter` call

Comment: @JoakimDanielson much easier/faster to use a set. Btw `map(\.serialNo)`

Comment: Maybe so but I just wanted to point out how close op was to having a solution and apart from my typo it needs to be compactMap, `arrayObj.compactMap(\.serialNo).filter { localArray.contains($0)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `forEach` to iterate your element and then check and append to the according to array.

```
localArray.forEach { number in
    arrayObj.contains(where: {$0.serialNo == number}) ? validScannedData.append(number) : inValidScannedData.append(number)
}
print(validScannedData)
print(inValidScannedData)
```